# Cannot override margin for input range in User Agent Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, html, input, html5-video

I have created a video seek bar that will update the frame based on the x position of your mouse when hovering over the video. The problem I've run into is with the user agent stylesheet for the input range.

There is a space between the bottom of the video and the input range below it. This space is seemingly coming from a 2px margin in the user agent sheet. Though I am able to edit the margin on the input range, this doesn't seem to get rid of that margin.

I've tried eliminating margins on the `-webkit-slider-runnable-track` pseudoselector as well, even though I am not using it. I've also tried eliminating margins on the video and the thumb as well. Using `!important` has no effect.

Setting the input to display:none gets rid of the input and the space. The margin is not coming from the video. The containing div is not a flexbox, but display: block. There is no excess whitespace in the html.

Note: This only needs to work on Chrome.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <video ...video stuff here...>
        <source ng-src="/some_url" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" ng-model="scanPosition" step="1" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
    background: transparent;  /*Otherwise white in Chrome */
    border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
    background-color: #227ea7;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
    background: #4f4f4f;
    width: 2%;
    height: 4px;
}
```

[image: chrome dev tools]

Comment: Fiddle showing margin above and below input: https://jsfiddle.net/jm509d9e/4/